# How to force same number of lines of text in CSS?

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm trying to fix the alignment of two boxes that have their location based on the vertical height of a few lines of text. In the example below the "Read more" buttons should have the same vertical location. Is the most effective way of doing this forcing the text above that to have equal number of lines, or is there a more efficient way?
https://theindividualitree.com/product-category/capacity-building/improved-daily-living/psychologists/

[image: Incorrect alignment example]

Comment: Let me know the link or the code please.

Comment: https://theindividualitree.com/product-category/capacity-building/improved-daily-living/psychologists/

Comment: Set a suitable height for `.woocommerce-loop-product__title` https://prnt.sc/q81d4a

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 0):

I used nested flex elements. First layer of flex gets you a uniform height. Second gets you an element that takes up any available space using `flex: 1;` in a `flex-flow: column;`...

HTML

```
<flex-box>
  <flex-item>
    <div>
      <p>Text</p>
      <p>Text</p>
      <p>Text</p>
      <p>Text</p>
      <p>Text</p>
    </div>
    <read-more>read more</read-more>  
  </flex-item>
  <flex-item>
    <div>
      <p>Text</p>
      <p>Text</p>
    </div>
    <read-more>read more</read-more>  
  </flex-item>
  <flex-item>
    <div>
      <p>Text</p>
    </div>
    <read-more>read more</read-more>  
  </flex-item>
</flex-box>
```

Sass

```
flex-box {
  display: flex;
  flex-item {
    min-width: 200px;
    background: #ccc;
    margin: 0.5em;
    padding: 1em;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
  }
  div {
    flex: 1;
  }
  read-more {
    background: #777;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0.5em 1em;
  }
}
```

Pen: https://codepen.io/bstees/pen/abzdNBj

Answer (score -1):

position absolute;
margin-bottom: X
^^^
If you mess around with the margins it should work